# Sinatra: List all .txt files of directory

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am new to Sinatra and have a problem in one of my projects.

I try to list all .txt files in the directory (notes), so i wrote this code:

```
get '/' do
files = Dir['notes/*.txt']
p files
end
```

It works perfectly fine and i get a string like this:

> example1.txtnotes/example2.txtnotes/example3.txtnotes

Than, I tried to split the string in parts, so I used:

```
files.split('/')
```

but this wont work. Sinatra shows me an ERROR page.

Does anybody know how to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dir returns an array, which has no #split method.  To split each filename in the array, you want this instead:

```
files.map { |f| f.split('/') }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please report what kind of error you are getting. You could try this one

> `files.split(/\//)`

Comment: It says at the top:
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `split' for #<Array:0x87b9fc8>

block in <top (required)>